# Find an index position within a matrix

Tags: matlab, search, matrix

In this example I have a matrix (a)

```
a = 1       2       3       7
    0.9     0.6     0.2    0.2
    0.8     17      72     15
```

My goal is to search through the matrix a and find the index position of the highest value that is not >= 72. The matrix is just for illustration but I would like to know how to do this for a matrix of any dimension where rows and columns equal (2x2 3x3 4x4 ...)

in this case I would like to calculate the fact that the highest number within the constraints is

Rows=3 Cols = 2

Thanks

Comment: I don't quite understand the question.  15 < 72, so why isn't the answer (3,4)?  And what is the "index position of the highest value" when you have two indices (row and column)?

Comment: They are looking for the highest number < 72, which would be 17, or, (3, 2)

Answer (score 4):

Step 1: determine the value you're interested in.

```
val = max(a(a<72));
```

Step 2: find the index of the element that corresponds to this value:

```
[r,c] = find(a==val,1,'first'); #%only take first element (this can be changed)
#r is the row index, c is the column index
```

You could also use linear indexing and `ind2sub`:

```
l = find(a==val); #%this time, find all elements that meet the criteria
[r,c] = ind2sub(size(a),l);
```

Here are links to documentation for [find](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) and [ind2sub](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html). You don't have to store the value (`val`) of interest either, you can just as easily put it all in one line.